# Making a new ArrayList containing objects the same as the first list?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, copy

I have an ArrayList containing custom objects.

What is the best way to make a separate ArrayList that has the exact same content, but isn't using the same references? As in, if I edit the first object in list1, it doesn't touch the first object in list2, but otherwise they look the same through and through.

Is it considered correct / good practice to do the following, or is there a built-in way?

```
List<MyObject> firstList = getArrayListFromSQLiteDb(criteria);
List<MyObject> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

for (MyObject object : firstList) {
    MyObject newObject = new MyObject();
    newObject.setField1(object.getField1());
    newObject.setField2(object.getField2());
    newObject.setField3(object.getField3());
    secondList.add(newObject);
}
```

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is just fine. Be careful though; if any of the fields are references, they're going to be copied over and it sounds like that isn't what you want.

Comment: List<MyObject> firstList = getArrayListFromSQLiteDb(criteria); and List<MyObject> secondList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(firstList);

Comment: @ManuAG If onky they would read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)...

Comment: @Manu & DjMethaneMan: And if you would read the question, you would understand that the asker doesn't just want a copy of the list, he wants a deep copy that also copies all contained objects (So that both lists have different objects in them). Neither the copy constructor nor the clone() function of ArrayList do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to clone the original ArrayList, thus not sharing references and having the other list remain untouched when you alter the original one. As @911DidBush mentioned, this will only work if the lists contents are cloneable and implement the clone() method correctly.

```
List<MyObject> firstList = getArrayListFromSQLiteDb(criteria);
List<MyObject> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

for(MyObject obj : firstList) {
    secondList.add(obj.clone());
}
```

Comment: You should probably also mention that this will only work if the lists contents are cloneable and implement the clone() method correctly. Otherwise you will get a CloneNotSupportedException